# Im getting a blank page in php

Tags: php, mysql, email

I'm trying to create a PHP e-mail activation system for my users, and when I run my script, it returns a blank page and my database was not updated. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

session_start()

$host="localhost"; 
$username="root"; 
$password="power1"; 
$db_name="members"; 
$tbl_name="users";

$link  = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect. Please contact us");
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB. Please contact us");

$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

if(isset($_SESSION[$queryString])) {
  $query = "SELECT * 
              FROM users 
             WHERE email = '$_SESSION[$queryString]'";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($queryString == $row[activationkey]) {
      echo "Congratulations! You have succesfully activated you account. You may now login.";

      $sql = ("UPDATE users 
                 SET activationkey = '' 
                 AND status = 'activated' 
               WHERE username = ".$row['username']);

      if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    }
  }
} ?>
```

Comment: Try adding "error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');" to the top of the file and see what errors are returned when you view the page again. The reason for getting a blank page is usually because there's an error somewhere and error reporting is turned off.

Comment: `$_SESSION[$queryString]` is this correct or you intended to use `$queryString`??

Comment: See my answer below regarding line 14

Comment: is `$_SESSION[$queryString]` really isset?

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `activationkey` is an uninitialized constant. You probably meant it to be a string.

Change this line:

```
if ($queryString == $row[activationkey]){
```

to this:

```
if ($queryString == $row['activationkey']){
```

And since you are accessing the elements of `$row` via string indexes, rather than numeric ones, you'll also want to change:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

to:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

Also, since you are accessing a session, you probably want to call [`session_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before the first reference to `$_SESSION`.

And finally, your code may be sending a malformed query to the database. Try changing this line:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$_SESSION[$queryString]'";
```

to this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION[$queryString]) . "'";
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\html\activate.php on line 14

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

Comment: @Joe: Odds are `$result === FALSE`. This happens when you send a malformed query to the database.

Comment: this key isnt their email it is there activation key so email wouldnt work in this case

Comment: @Joe: echo some debugging lines to the browser so you can better understand what's going on. Start with the query. If you add `echo $query;` right before the call to `mysql_query()`, what do you see?

Comment: im sorry where do i put it exactly? becuase where i have it now it doesnt echo anything

Comment: @Joe: immediately before this line: `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: im not getting anything from that

Comment: At the end, after the last `}`, add this line: `else { echo "session value wasn't set"; }`. What gets outputted now?

Comment: I'm still getting: Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\html\activate.php on line 16

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\html\activate.php on line 16

Comment: any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @Joe: Did you add the call to session_start() at the top of the script?

Comment: yes and im using the updated code that @OMGPonies added and now im getting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\html\activate.php on line 5

Comment: fixed that but my only question is why does is say email= that key in the url is not the email its an activation key so should i change email to activationkey

Comment: it also says session value wasnt set

Answer (score 1):

You probably just have an error... PHP is notorious for blowing up and not letting you know about it. Try adding this to the top of your code and running the file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Just don't leave it in when you make you're application available to other users..

Answer (score 1):

Your query may not be returning any value, try to print the sql and see what's wrong with the query

Answer (score 1):

while using sessions, you need to give

```
  <?php
   session_start();
```

at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0):

I think the lines with `$_SESSION[$queryString]` may be your issue, try replacing all instances with `$_SESSION['QUERY_STRING']` or `$queryString`

Answer (score 0):

only message is printed if you execution goes in

if ($queryString == $row[activationkey])

statement..

I think $queryString does not get any match with all db vals...

one more thing if activationkey is table column then it has to be covered by single or double quotes like this $row['activationkey']